# bazel coverage is failing while bazel test is working fine

Tags: code-coverage, bazel, coverage.py, bazel-rules, bazel-java

I have the pytest file called `sample_unit_test.py` and `BUILD.bazel` mentioning the target and other details. When I run `bazel test //folder_path:sample_unit_test`, it is passing the test but when I run `bazel coverage` with the same target failing with the following error:

```
 LCOV_MERGER_CMD='bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/remote_coverage_tools/Main --coverage_dir=/worker/build/89bf270e28a51440/root/_coverage/<mypath>/_test/test   --output_file=/worker/build/89bf270e28a51440/root/bazel-out/k8-opt/testlogs/<some_path>/coverage.dat   --filter_sources=/usr/bin/.+   --filter_sources=/usr/lib/.+   --filter_sources=/usr/include.+   --filter_sources=/Applications/.+   --filter_sources=.*external/.+   --source_file_manifest=/worker/build/89bf270e28a51440/root/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/<some_path>.instrumented_files'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ JAVA_RUNFILES=
+ exec bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/remote_coverage_tools/Main --coverage_dir=/worker/build/89bf270e28a51440/root/_coverage/<mypath>_unit_test/test --output_file=/worker/build/89bf270e28a51440/root/bazel-out/k8-opt/testlogs/<mypath>/coverage.dat --filter_sources=/usr/bin/.+ --filter_sources=/usr/lib/.+ --filter_sources=/usr/include.+ --filter_sources=/Applications/.+ '--filter_sources=.*external/.+' --source_file_manifest=/worker/build/89bf270e28a51440/root/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/<some_path>_unit_test.instrumented_files
/worker/build/89bf270e28a51440/root/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/remote_coverage_tools/Main: Cannot locate runfiles directory. (Set $JAVA_RUNFILES to inhibit searching.)
Action details (cached result): <some_link>
```

Exact command: `bazel coverage --test_env=PYTHON_COVERAGE=/usr/local/bin/coverage  --test_env=COVERAGE_GCOV_PATH=/usr/bin/gcov //<path>:sample_unit_test --keep_going` \

How and What do I set `$JAVA_RUNFILES`? If bazel test is able to auto set this variable then why bazel coverage is struggling? 
Please help.
Your help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you

System Configuration: 
**Bazel version**: 5.4.0 (I can't update Bazel because of other dependency) 
OS: Ubuntu